# I am able to change the action bar background color. but I can't change the text color, how can I do this?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My themes.xml file is..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@style/MyActionBar1</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#45AEEA</item>


</style>
```

so how to change the color of the text in action bar? the above code is not working. it only changing the background color.

```
  <style name="MyActionBar1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">

      <item name="android:">#000000</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this help you....
styles.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
      <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
      </style>

      <style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle"parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
      </style>

      <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
      </style>
    </resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <item name="android:textColor">#fe4647</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the attributes in a style like this

```
<style name="MyActionBar1" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge,the id of Action Bar Title is hidden.
So first you have to fetch the id of that Action Bar like this :

```
int ActionBarTitleID = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
```

Now use settext on this ID like

```
TextView yourTextView = (TextView)findViewById(ActionBarTitleID);
yourTextView.setTextColor(colorId);
```